# How to set Laravel fallback locale dynamically?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

I try to set fallback locale dynamically through web using config set with the key of `app.fallback_locale`. But its did not work.

`config()->set('app.fallback_locale', 'ms')`

Is there something I missing?

Comment: Is `fallback_locale` set in your `config/app.php`?  What does "it did not work" mean, exactly, how are you testing and what are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Set `fallback_locale` in `app.php`,

```
'fallback_locale' => 'ms',
```

Try clearing your config cache, before accessing it

```
php artisan config:clear
```

You can try using `php artisan tinker` and run

```
config('app.locale');
OR    
App::getLocale()
```

Hope this works in your case!!